# Email Signature mail flow images break but text in signature works fine

Tags: html, email, exchange-server, html-email

I'm trying to implement a company wide email signature mail flow rule across all email addresses that are assigned to the exchange recipients because I've noticed that with everyone trying to create there own signature on the client side, it doesn't look consistent with the spacing etc. Therefore, I decided to implement the company email signatures on the server using exchange server mailflow. I successfully managed to implement the rule in exchange server and tried testing it on my own company email address. This works fine to where the text in the email signature shows up as well as the images. However, when I add another recipient to the mail flow rule and enforce the policy, we tried replying back and fourth to one another and his email signature shows up but the HTML template that contains the images in the email signature breaks and shows the actual text in the email signature.

**Here is an example of my email signature showing fine when I compose an email to myself. As you can see it works just fine.**

[image]

**Here is an example of a person I implemented the rule for also but there email signature breaks and doesn't look like mine at all. The text in the email signature shows up fine but the images break and display as text in the email signature.**

[image]

I removed the sensitive parks of the email for personal reasons but I got complaints from the recipient that when they send an email to a person outside the organization it works fine but when they send an email to me within the organization it breaks and I'm not sure why.

Here is the HTML email template I enforced in the policy:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
 <body>
   <div
     style="padding-bottom:5px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: 18px;"
   >
     <a href="" target="_blank"
       ><img
         src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Red-Logo.png"
         alt="Red Logo"
         width="200"
     /></a>

     <br />
     <span style="font-weight: bold;" class="name"
       ><strong>%%FirstName%% %%LastName%%</strong></span
     >
     <span class="title-sep">/</span> <span class="jobtitle">%%Title%%</span>
     <br />
     <span class="email">Email: %%Email%% </span> <br />
     <span class="office-phone"> %%Office%%</span> <br />
   </div>

   <div>
     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/CompanyNameisHere" target="_blank"
       ><img
         src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Red-Facebook.png"
         width="20"/></a
     >&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a
       href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/CompanyNameisHere"
       target="_blank"
       ><img
         src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Red-LinkedIn.png"
         width="20"/></a
     >&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a href="https://www.instagram.com/CompanyNameisHere/" target="_blank"
       ><img
         src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Red-Instagram.png"
         width="20"/></a
     >&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a href="https://twitter.com/CompanyNameisHere" target="_blank"
       ><img
         src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Red-Twitter.png"
         width="20"/></a
     >&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a
       href="https://www.youtube.com/user/CompanyNameisHere"
       target="_blank"
       ><img
         src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Red-YouTube.png"
         width="20"/></a
     >&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/CompanyNameisHere/" target="_blank"
       ><img
         src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Red-Pinterest.png"
         width="20"/></a
     >&nbsp;&nbsp;
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried removing the line breaks before each closing `>` tags?

Comment: I could do that but that wouldn't explain why it works fine for me but not the other person when I enforced the policy through exchange server mail flow rule?